# Structure Description of p-groups of nilpotency class 2, where p is an odd prime.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, p-groups

Suppose $G=\langle a,b \mid [a,b]^{p^\gamma}=[a,b,a]=[a,b,b]=1, a^{p^{\alpha}}=[a,b]^{p^\rho}, b^{p^{\beta}}=[a,b]^{p^\sigma}\rangle$, where $\alpha>\beta\geq \gamma\geq1$ and $0\leq\sigma<\rho<\min\{\gamma,\sigma+\alpha-\beta\}$. From these conditions, we obtain $\alpha>\beta\geq \gamma>\rho>\sigma\geq0$.

If we consider the following group, not in the category of the above groups (since $\alpha=\beta\;\text{and}\;\sigma=\gamma$ here), $G_1=\langle a,b \mid [a,b]^{27}=[a,b,a]=[a,b,b]=1, a^{81}=[a,b]^{9}, b^{81}=[a,b]^{27}=1\rangle$ , we have $G_1 \cong 
(\langle c\rangle \times \langle a\rangle)\rtimes \langle b\rangle, \;\text{with}\; [a, b] = a^9c, [b, c] = [a,b]^9,|a| =243, |b| = 81, |c| =9, |[a, b]| = 27; \text{i.e.}, G_1\cong(\mathbb{Z_{243}}\times \mathbb{Z_{9}})\rtimes\mathbb{Z_{81}},$  using [1](https://userweb.ucs.louisiana.edu/%7Eavm1260/preprints/ammpaper.pdf), page 21,(iii),with $(t+w-v,u,v;w,v)=(4,4,3,2,3)$.

My question is: Can we write a group $G$ as a semidirect product of some groups, such as $G_1$ defined in [1](https://userweb.ucs.louisiana.edu/%7Eavm1260/preprints/ammpaper.pdf) ? If yes, what will be those generators and relations?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Use `$\langle X\mid R\rangle$` for $\langle X\mid R\rangle$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.